# NullPointer Exception in onPostExecute in AsyncTask

Tags: php, android, string, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am dealing with my web services and I got a strange problem. I am not able to solve this as I am new to android development. I am getting null pointer exception in onPostExecute() method of Async Task. This is happening when I am comparing the result with a string.

```
if (result.contains("Duplicate"))           or 
if (result.equals("Duplicate"))             or
if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Duplicate"))   or
```

all three give error. I have printed the value of result by System.out.println(result); and it shows **null**

To make my problem weirder this happens only sometimes especially when my boss tests it. Other times it works wonderfully. The device and the network both remain same. Earlier it used to happen only on emulator. I used to restart eclipse and the problem used to get solved.

Please help me out!

**Code**

```
private void startDownload() {

    new AddTask().execute(FILENAME);
}

public class AddTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ContactDetails.this, "Loading",
                "Please Wait...");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


            if (result.contains("Duplicate")) { //---- here error comes

                int ecolor = -16777216; // whatever color you want
                String estring = "Account with this email already exists!!";
                ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(
                        ecolor);
                SpannableStringBuilder ssbuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                        estring);
                ssbuilder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, estring.length(), 0);
                et2.setError(ssbuilder);
                dialog.dismiss();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ContactDetails.this, "Account Created!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
                myDialog = new Dialog(ContactDetails.this);
                myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.email_alert);
                myDialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
                myDialog.setCancelable(true);

                // for OK
                Button ok = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.alertOk);
                ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(ContactDetails.this,
                                Login.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                myDialog.show();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        is = null;
            individual();


        return is;
    }


    public void individual() {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://website.com/contact.php");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    10);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", str1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", str2));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", str3));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Address", str5));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pin", str11));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("City", spt1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("State", str12));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone_visibility",
                    str_radio));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("No", str7));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            // httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(is);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**---EDIT---**

What can be the reason of getting a null value as result? Is it a network problem? 
Is there a way with which I can ensure that I will not get a null result?
My app will not function properly if I get null

Comment: Why didn't you check for NPE??

Comment: yep... validate result String in onPostExecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check for NPE on result

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    if(result == null)
    {
        // handle null result, debug or whatever
        return;
    }
    .... 
    //rest of your code
}
```

**EDIT**
I believe here is your problem

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

response maybe getting null value, so that `response.getEntity();` will raise exception, and  `is = EntityUtils.toString(entity);` will neve be reached thus it will have null value
and in you doInBackground you return `is` which is null :) so you need to handle that null value and accept the fact that sometimes you will get null value. cheers

Answer (score 2):

check whether you are getting data or not from result...

```
if(result!=null){
// here check  the things you need


}
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the `result` is `null` or not..if not then only perform your operations..like below..

```
if(result!=null){
if (result.contains("Duplicate"))           or 
if (result.equals("Duplicate"))             or
if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Duplicate"))   or
}
```

Comment: yes but why does result comes null? required record is present in the database. also in php i am echoing a message

Answer (score 1):

You're catching many exceptions in `individual()`. When one of them happens, your `result` may still be null but you won't know that.

You should either:

1. Change the exception catching code and store additional information that an exception happened and use that information in `onPostExecute`.
2. Just accept that `result` can be null and handle it correctly in `onPostExecute` (checking for null and doing some appropriate action).

Comment: yes but why does result comes null? required record is present in the database. also in php i am echoing a message

Comment: It can be any of the exceptions, you're calling a server, anything can happen. Have you actually tried debugging and see if it goes into any of the `catch` block?

Comment: No I test by putting toasts and system.out statements. I still have to learn to properly debug

Answer (score 0):

```
protected String doInBackground
```

returns *String*

You are returning *null*.

```
onPostExecute(String result)
```

processes that *String*.

You can not call *"contains"* on a *null*.

Fix:

```
    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    is = individual();

    return is;
}

public String individual() {
```

... put your JSON data into a String ...